# How to fetch resource group name( with pattern matching) using Azurecli

Tags: azure

I set my az account to current subscription. And I am trying to fetch the resource name ending with (example "***kafka" ). How can i do it.

I tried with `az group list -n '***kafka'`

> validation error: Parameter 'resource_group_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve this.

First is to go with transforming json output to proper object for PowerShell as described in this thread:

- [how do you select just one property from an array of “results” from the Azure command 'az group list in powershell'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738011/how-do-you-select-just-one-property-from-an-array-of-results-from-the-azure-co)

Second it to use `--query` global parameter for Azure CLI:

```
az group list --query "[?contains(name,'kafka')].name"
```

But remember to use at least PowerShell 6.2 as previous versions have an issue:

- [powershell --query error #9047](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9047)